# Customize the NavigationBar backBarButton

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I use the code below to customize the backBarButtonItem, because I need to change the text color.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The color changed but the text font looks weird. See, the "Back" is not clear around the edges.
I don't know why this happens. Does anyone has any idea about this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text has a shadow, which is set upward from the text.  textlabel's have a shadowOffset value and a shadowColor value.  You can either offset the shadow differently to make it look better or change the color to [UIColor clearColor] - both of which could help.

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
[attributes setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowColor];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Replacing your code with the above snippet will set the text color to black, and the shadow to clear.  This should remove the bluriness.  The blur is actually caused by a shadow being cast by the text.  By making the shadow a 'clearColor' it becomes invisible.  An alternative would be changing the offset so that it looks like it's being cast downwards instead of up; or change the color to something distinctly different from black so that you can distinguish between the text and it's shadow.

Comment: What? I'm not sure I understand what you are talking about please could you give more detail and how this solves the problem. Please update your answer don't just comment.

Comment: I edited my answer with a code snippet and some more detail.  Hopefully that clarifies things a little.

Comment: Thanks, change color to clear can solve it. And I am curious how to change the shadow offset, Could you show me that , appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: shadowOffset takes in a UIOffset.  So you could for instance set your color for the shadow to green (just to make it visible) then set the offset like so:
[attributes setValue:NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1.0, 1.0)] forKey:UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset];  (place this line before the setTitleTextAttributes:forState: line).  This will set the shadow to appear to the bottom left.  The Offset value can be anything you want, the first value is distance left/right (with negative being left, and positive being right), and second value is distance up/down (negative/positive respectively).